# "Knave upon the Cross" and lines by Edward Bulwer-Lytton origin

Tags: etymology, nineteenth-century-english

My great-grandfather included the lines below in an entry in his Civil War diary dated 4/17/1863 to note the 6th Corps of the Army of the Potomac added a white cross to their hats. I believe it's by Edward Bulwer-Lytton. Does anyone know the origin of these lines pre-Civil War?

"In ancient days, and no great loss,
They hung a knave upon the cross.
How differently they now behave,
They hang the cross upon the knave."

Comment: I’m voting to close this question as it is about literature rather than how the language works (and so belongs on Literature.SE).

Comment: The poems of Bulwer-Lytton can be found at http://www.gutenberg.org/files/34298/34298-h/34298-h.htm The lines quoted are not among them.

Comment: The only match found by Google for "cross upon the knave" is this very question.